# plotting vectors between 3 points randomly in R

Tags: r, vector, plot

I am working with R

basically there are three coordinates: `a=(0,0)`, `b=(3,4)`, `c=(4,1)`
starting from the `origin(0,0)`, I have to randomly choose one of these three points and plot a line HALFWAY towards it and repeat the steps for 100 times.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are those supposed to be open intervals for (x,y,z )-coordinates? If these are in 2d-space then why do this 100 times? And since this looks like homeworky question at the moment, you might get more attention by showing what you have done so far ( eg, what packages you are planning to use) or if not homework, then what is this supposed to be in the service of seeing when it's done?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution abusing the `Reduce` function:

```
# get 100 random points
pts <- list(a,b,c)
points <- sample(pts, 100, replace=TRUE)

# all half-way points in the path
hws <- Reduce(function(x,y) (x+y)/2, points, init=c(0,0), accumulate=TRUE)

# plot
plot(do.call(rbind, pts))
lines(do.call(rbind, hws))
```

#### Result:

[image: walk]